# Area inside $r = 1 + \cos \alpha $

Tags: integration, area, polar-coordinates

We are studying polar equations.

> Calculate the surface inside $r = 1 + \cos \alpha $ and outside $r = 1$.

I know the area inside $r = 1 + \cos \alpha $ being $\frac{3 \pi}2$ because I [calculated](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1%2Bcos%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B2%7D) $\int_0^{2\pi} 1 + \cos(\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}\alpha$

The given solution is $2+\frac{\pi}4$

How can I visualize this integral? Which formula I should use to obtain the answer and why?

A formula we are given is $$S =\int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1}\frac{r^2(\alpha)}{2}d\alpha~.$$

Comment: Why don't you use the given formula ??

Comment: I used the formula for the first equation but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: This is not what you show.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The area of a rectangle of height $y$ and basis $dx$ is $y\,dx$.

The area of a circular sector of radius $r$ and aperture $d\alpha$ is $\dfrac{r^2}2\,d\alpha$.

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand what to fill in for $r$ when two equations are given.

Comment: @ScoobyDuh Study the intersection of the curves.

Comment: I see it now I didn't use the correct formula in my post but I did in the Symbolab link. Anyways I managed to find the correct solution by first calculating $$\int_\frac{-π}2^\frac{π}2 \frac{(1+cos(x))^2}2 dα$$ this gave me $$\frac{6π+16}8$$ Next I calculated the area of the unit circle $$\int_\frac{-π}2^\frac{π}2 \frac{1^2}2 dα$$ which gave me $$\frac{π}2$$ $$\frac{6π+16}8 - \frac{π}2$$ gives the correct solution.

Now I did this all graphical. I'm wondering how I can find the right bounderies of the integral by calculation. I can imagine the graphical way isn't always an option

Comment: @ScoobyDuh: well done! Now you solve $1+\cos\alpha\le1$.

Comment: Thank you I understand it now. And u mean greater or equal than one, right? Because we need the area outside $r=1$.

Comment: @ScoobyDuh: I mean less or equal because we need the area outside $r=1$.

Comment: I don't understand that